# Asp.Net Core Web Api hide controllers and actions by api-key authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am converting an Asp.Net Web Api project to Asp.Net Core with .net6.

This project uses a custom Api-Key authentication and authorization method to give access to some of the controllers and actions.

In the old project, when opening the swagger documentation, the only controllers and actions displayed are the ones that do not require authentication.
Once the user inserts the api key and clicks on **Explore** button, the authorized controllers and actions shows up in documentation.

To do this, in the legacy project, I used `IOperationFilter` and `IDocumentFilter` to hide controllers and actions if not authorized.

This is working because when you click on **Explore** button after providing the api key, the page is refreshed and, at every refresh of the page, the `IOperationFilter` and `IDocumentFilter` are applied.

In Asp.Net Core, it seems that the `IOperationFilter` and `IDocumentFilter` are applied only at startup, and, in addition, the new **Authorize** button does not reload the page, and works only client side to provide authorization to the subsequent user interactions with the **Try it out** button present on every action.

Is it possibile to do something similar in Asp.Net Core, or should I drop that feature in the new version?

Answer (score 0):

I found something may help you :
In asp.net core Swagger construct the UI page with a json file as below :

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c=>
{                    
   c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json","SwaggerFilterv1"); 
});
```

This json file is constructed with the options you configured when you registed the service

Then I tried to copy the content of json file to the static file in the project ,deleted part of the path(you could also apply the filters and copy the json file directly ),and  replaced  the  json file constructed by .net core

It worked as excepted : Some of the Api was missing

and you may inject your js file to control it(Add a request header you if auth succeeded and refresh the page and check request header with middleware):

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c=>
    {                    
       ......
       c.InjectJavascript("")
    });
```

I tried to branch the pipeline(I omitted the Authentication process just tried to check the query para):

```
app.UseWhen(x =>x.Request.Query.ContainsKey("Key"),
                     app =>app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                        {                            
                            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/somejson.json", "SwaggerFilter v1");                            

                        }));
app.UseWhen(......)
```

The Result:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting, but this solution uses a query string parameter.  
The Authorize button does not reload the page nor adds query string parameters but adds only an header to the subsequent requests.  
So I don't know how to apply this solution.  
In addition, the endpoints that should be visible are subject to authorization permissions, so an Api Key can show the method A, and another not. I cannot use static swagger.json files